# How do I fill the succeeding null values with a preceeding value in csv file in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I fill the succeeding null values with a preceeding value in csv file in python/pandas?

My data :
[image]

Required Output :
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a good  pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. Also [please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have, obtained by reading "excel" or "csv" as you described :

```
  type   count
0      A      1
1    NaN      2
2    NaN      3
3    NaN      4
4    NaN      4
5    NaN      5
6      B      5
7    NaN      6
8    NaN      3
9    NaN     77
10   NaN      7
11   NaN     88
12     C     88
13   NaN      8
14   NaN      8
```

Then

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

returns:

```
 type   count
0      A      1
1      A      2
2      A      3
3      A      4
4      A      4
5      A      5
6      B      5
7      B      6
8      B      3
9      B     77
10     B      7
11     B     88
12     C     88
13     C      8
14     C      8
```

Comment: `fillna` is redundant here. You can directly use: `df.type = df.type.ffill()`.